# Unable to create an Infopath form that pulls data from a SP list

Tags: 2010, list, infopath, infopath-data-connections

I have created several Infopath forms that pull data from specific SP lists. In these cases I was able to open Infopath, select the SP list option and paste my website URL in to connect to my list after providing my credentials. This would allow me to edit my forms and then publish the changes back to the list.

However, sometimes when I open Infopath and try to connect to my site to create a new form/list connection, I get an error pop up that I can't even read:

[image: error message]

I am still able to edit forms that I have previously connected to lists. However, this error is preventing me from creating any new forms for my site and establishing a connection to a new list.

I am using Sharepoint 2010, and Infopath 2013 (which may be the problem but it's odd that it sometimes works and other times doesn't).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found a very strange solution to this issue:

1. Open Infopath Designer
2. Open from recent a file called 'template.xsn' and login with your credentials
3. Once your form opens, click File > New
4. Proceed to make the data connection you had an issue with, and it should connect and open a new form using the data from your SP list.
5. You can now close the template form that you initially opened.